# UFT-Insight Objects

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

Can we fetch the text present inside an Insight Object In UFT 14.1 ??

I have tried GetROProperty of the InsightObject,but it did not fetch the text inside the Insight object .

Getvisible text of the Insight Object HomePage fetches all the text on screen but ,the content is not stable .

Is there any method to  fetch value from Insight object

Comment: Have you tried getting the visible text using the screen co-ordinates ? you can read the co-ordinates of the insight object and then get the text within those co-ordinates.